# Select element that is not a descendant of a classed element

Tags: css, sass

I have a table#data_table that I would want to style but I dont want the css to apply to its child table.table-condensed which is also a child of div.vue-daterange-picker as you can see on the [html tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IT9Q.png)
I tried this but it seems that :not does'nt work with nested css :

```
:not(.vue-daterange-picker) table
{
    tr {...}
    td {...}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the datepicker table has a unique class, `table-condensed`. You can use this to not select it.

Also includes direct child selectors to prevent a parent table from messing with your datepicker.

```
table:not(.table-condensed)
{
    & > thead, & > tbody {
       & > tr {
          // ...
          & > td {
             // ...
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, well you'll need to update your question to specify that! I'll update my answer to accomodate.

Comment: Does my updated answer resolve your issue?

Comment: Moreover, I don't want to use the id `data_table` because I want the style to apply to all tables but not to those that are contained in `div.vue-daterange-picker`, that's why I think I should use :not() selector

Comment: Well, you can't really do that super easily. You need some identifier to pick out which tables you want. Consider adding classes to tables you do want styling on.

Comment: Don't you think it is possible with the :not() selector? Without nested it works but with nested scss it doesn't work

Comment: You can't really find elements that aren't inside of an element. The best you can do is find a common parent element that has that tag, and then search inside them. If you searched for all elements that aren't daterangepicker, then search inside them for tables; a single one of daterangepicker's children would not be filtered out... which means that table would still be styled.

Comment: You would be able to do some mounted logic and `querySelectorAll('vue-daterange-picker')`, then `querySelectorAll('table')` on that; and just add some class to them that would make them be ignored in other table styling. Hard, if not impossible to do this with strictly SCSS though.

Comment: Ok, thanks again for helping but I still can't understand why `:not()` selector doesn't work with nested css, your solution should work but maybe it is not the most proper way to do it

Comment: If you are confused about it, please ask what you are confused about. You need to be more specific. And you don't have to be rude, I've spent almost a dozen minutes trying to help you on this.

Comment: `:not(.vue-daterange-picker)` will select any items that are NOT the date-range picker, **this includes its children**. This makes it incapable of being used to filter out anything that is not a direct child.

Comment: Check my answer again, I just updated that. Did some more detailed looking and this may work for you.

Comment: Your last answer doesn't work because we should write all the parent of each element and the code would become unreadable eg `thead > tr {...}` then `tbody > tr {...}`

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm confused about what you mean.

Comment: Yep you're right, typo on my part. How's it look now?

Comment: There's probably no way to do it and I must understand that `.class` is actually not the opposite of `:not(.class)` that is quite confusing.. Although, will use your solution until I realise (or not) there is a more proper way to do. Thanks again for your time buddy!